# Почему у Монтеня не стоит запятая в выделенном фрагменте?

Tags: пунктуация

> Нет человека, которому пристало бы меньше моего затевать разговоры о
> памяти. Ведь я не нахожу в себе ни малейших следов её и не думаю,
> чтобы во всем мире существовала **другая память столь же чудовищно
> немощная**. Все остальные мои способности незначительны и вполне
> заурядны. Но в отношении этой я представляю собой нечто совсем
> исключительное и редкостное и потому заслуживаю, пожалуй, известности
> и громкого имени.

[Глава IX.
О лжецах](http://www.informaxinc.ru/lib/science/monten_essey.html)

---

Почему я хочу запятую после "памяти", с каким правилом путаю?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ведь я не нахожу в себе ни малейших следов её и не думаю, чтобы во всем мире существовала **другая память столь же чудовищно немощная**.

Запятых и пауз нет.

Это не совсем стандартный вариант с **двумя особенностями**.

1) Между местоимением другая и определительным оборотом отношения **не пояснительные, а неоднородные.**

**У Розенталя:** Возможность вариантов пунктуации объясняется различным толкованием смысла предложения; ср.: Я хочу купить **другой кожаный** портфель (у меня уже имеется кожаный портфель). — Я хочу купить **другой, кожаный** портфель (у меня имеется портфель, но не кожаный).

Признак сохраняется: **другой портфель с тем же признаком.**

2) Определительный оборот обозначает отличительный признак, на него падает логическое ударение, поэтому он н**е обособляется в постпозиции.**

Сравнить: не думаю, чтобы во всем мире существовала **другая столь же чудовищно немощная** память.

Признак сохраняется: другая память с тем же признаком

Answer (score 3):

А мне запятой совсем не хочется, поискал почему.

> Не обособляются распространённые и однородные одиночные определения,
>   стоящие после существительного, если существительное нуждается в
>   определении, **если без этого определения высказывание не имеет
>   законченного смысла**. В устной речи именно на эти определения падает
>   логическое ударение, а пауза между определяемым словом и определением
>   отсутствует. Например: *Вместо весёлой петербургской жизни, ожидала
>   меня скука в стороне глухой и отдалённой (Пушкин).*

https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/714-233_obosoblenie_soglasovannyh_opredelenii.html

В нашем случае память от своего определительного оборота не отделить: полный смысл заключён в совокупном выражении (память вполне определённого свойства - о существовании в мире памяти как таковой говорить нет смысла).